Shader error in 'Shader Graphs/Screen_Graph': 'SHADERGRAPH_BAKED_GI' in Vision Pro Hello World Build
Installed the latested xcode and opened the helloworld sample project.
When build-run, I have received the following Error.
Shader error in 'Shader Graphs/Screen_Graph': 'SHADERGRAPH_BAKED_GI': Too few arguments to a macro call. at Assets/Scenes/Terminal/Shaders/Screen_Graph.shadergraph(2909)
Compiling Subshader: 0, Pass: GBuffer, Vertex program with FOG_LINEAR _REFLECTION_PROBE_BOX_PROJECTION
Platform defines: UNITY_ENABLE_DETAIL_NORMALMAP UNITY_FRAMEBUFFER_FETCH_AVAILABLE UNITY_LIGHTMAP_DLDR_ENCODING UNITY_LIGHT_PROBE_PROXY_VOLUME UNITY_NEEDS_RENDERPASS_FBFETCH_FALLBACK UNITY_NO_DXT5nm UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF1 UNITY_SPECCUBE_BLENDING UNITY_SPECCUBE_BOX_PROJECTION UNITY_USE_DITHER_MASK_FOR_ALPHABLENDED_SHADOWS
Disabled keywords: DOTS_INSTANCING_ON FOG_EXP FOG_EXP2 INSTANCING_ON SHADER_API_GLES30 UNITY_ASTC_NORMALMAP_ENCODING UNITY_COLORSPACE_GAMMA UNITY_ENABLE_REFLECTION_BUFFERS UNITY_HALF_PRECISION_FRAGMENT_SHADER_REGISTERS UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER1 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER2 UNITY_HARDWARE_TIER3 UNITY_LIGHTMAP_FULL_HDR UNITY_LIGHTMAP_RGBM_ENCODING UNITY_METAL_SHADOWS_USE_POINT_FILTERING UNITY_NO_FULL_STANDARD_SHADER UNITY_NO_SCREENSPACE_SHADOWS UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF2 UNITY_PBS_USE_BRDF3 UNITY_PRETRANSFORM_TO_DISPLAY_ORIENTATION UNITY_UNIFIED_SHADER_PRECISION_MODEL UNITY_VIRTUAL_TEXTURING _FORWARD_PLUS

This particular error has been resolved by removing older platforms installed in Xcode. I will describe the detail.

First in Xcode, do Command + ','.

In Platforms tab, delete all older versions of platforms you are using.



